# Name of iPhone app

Tags: iphone, app-store

I hope this is not outside the scope of the this forum.

I was just wondering if anyone knows of any rules or guidelines for namming your iPhone app. Particulary I want mine to start with the letter 'i' as in iAwesomeApp (for example). But I thought maybe Apple wouldn't allow it because it is too close to their own marketing scheme i.e. it is too close to iTunes, iPod, iPhone etc.

What do we think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty if `i` apps but you need to stay clear of any other Apple brands like

- Pod / Pad
- MacBook etc

You probably want something short for your display name so to avoid the `...` in the middle if it's too long.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the iTunesApp store. There are many, many apps that start with "i" for the same reasons, so I think it must be fine. There isn't anything I've read in the guidelines that disallows it.

Answer (score 1):

Steer clear of any registered trademarks. You can get away with putting trademarks in your keywords sometimes, but Apple can and will reject your app for that as well so I would avoid it if possible.